# cgi script served as plain text when called from .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, cgi, errordocument

I'm Running Apache 2.2 on the RackSpace CloudSites.
I have a Perl CGI script that works fine if called directly via URL. I want to use the script as a custom ErrorDocument, but instead of being parsed and run it displays the text as plain text.

Here is my .htaccess file:


`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

Options +ExecCGI

ErrorDocument 404 /cgi/test.cgi`

Any help wold be appreciated!

Comment: When the cgi works fine are they inside cgi-bin or outside ? that could be your problem if the cgi is not allowed to run outside of the cgi-bin folder so you would need to put the test.cgi inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Prix,The cgi is in a sub-dir of the document root with ExecCGI enabled. So it's outside the cgi-bin but enabled. It runs fine from this location just not if invoked by the .htaccess' ErrorDocument directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with CloudSites support:
1. I had my .htaccess in a directory which won't allow the running of cgi scripts, no matter what options you add. I had to move the .htaccess up one level and refer to a file in a child dir.
2. They said the popular way to do this now is to use PHP instead of CGI.